# Rotate cube in blender with python

Tags: python, rotation, blender, mesh, blender-2.67

I have created a cube using python in blender

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(radius=1, location=(x, y, z))
```

I want to rotate the cube around its z-axis with a random angle between -180, 180 degrees. Is there an argument or do I need a new line of code? How do i accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: this is probably a better question for http://blender.stackexchange.com/ if it's not in the [documentation](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78a_release/info_quickstart.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a rotation argument to [`primitive_cube_Add`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.ops.mesh.html#bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add). Note that python rotation options use radians, so you may need to use [`math.radians(x)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.radians)

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(radius=1, location=(x,y,z), rotation=(rx,ry,rz))
```

You can also directly change the [rotatation of the object](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.rotation_euler) after you have created it. After `primitive_cube_add()` the new object is selected and is the active object.

```
bpy.context.active_object.rotation_mode = 'XYZ'
bpy.context.active_object.rotation_euler = (rx, ry, rz)
```

While the above example works it is more correct to specify the rotation using a [`mathutils.Euler`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/mathutils.html#mathutils.Euler) or [`mathutils.Quaternion`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/mathutils.html#mathutils.Quaternion) object.